# The Earth 2 Pantheon

Tags: dc

In the new Earth 2 series we have encountered Mercury and the "embodiment of the Earth's energy".  Has DC provides any information on what Earth 2's pantheon looks like, since we've encountered both Greek gods and nature spirits so far?  Is it all-encompassing (should we expect other cameos), or is it just adhoc, or is it based on some existing DC mythos?